# backpack-for-laravel select2_multiple field with same pivot table but different fields on the same form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I-am in the process of making this project where I have two (or more) fields having the same pivot table and am using the relationship type on backpack-for-laravel. What i want to do is have these two fields work independently.

So let's say I want to have one field where the user selects thickness while in the other field the user can select shading suppose.

The issue is that these two fields have the same pivot table and the same relationship set up in the model and therefore only one of them would show up in the same form. I do know that HTML forms replace the fields with the same "name" attribute but I'd like to know how can i get around solving this issue and have the fields work independently maintaining the select2_multiple functionality.

> Table structure (Collection has n-n relationship with Collection Attributes)

```
Collection:
 id
 collection_name
 .....

CollectionAttributes:
 id
 attribute_name
 attribute_value
 ...

CollectionAttrValues
 fk_col_id
 fk_attr_val_id
```

> Model relationship method:

```
public function collectionAttributeValues()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\AttributeValue', 'collections_attr', 'fk_collection_id', 'fk_attr_val_id');
    }
```

> Controller fields code:

```
CRUD::addField([   // relationship
            'type' => "relationship",
            'name' => 'collectionAttributeValues', // the method on your model that defines the relationship
        
            // OPTIONALS:
            'label' => "Thickness",
            'attribute' => "attr_val", // foreign key attribute that is shown to user (identifiable attribute)
            'entity' => 'collectionAttributeValues', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            'model' => "App\Models\AttributeValue", // foreign key Eloquent model
            // 'placeholder' => "Select a category", // placeholder for the select2 input
            'options'   => (function ($query) {
                $thickness_id = \App\Models\Attribute::select('attr_id')
                ->where('fk_attr_category', 1)
                ->where('attr_type', 'collection')
                ->where('attr_name', 'Thickness')->get()->first()->attr_id;

                return $query->orderBy('attr_val', 'desc')->where('fk_attr_id', $thickness_id)->get();
            }),
         ]);

         CRUD::addField([   // relationship
            'type' => "relationship",
            'name' => 'collectionAttributeValues', // the method on your model that defines the relationship
        
            // OPTIONALS:
            'label' => "Shading",
            'attribute' => "attr_val", // foreign key attribute that is shown to user (identifiable attribute)
            'entity' => 'collectionAttributeValues', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            'model' => "App\Models\AttributeValue", // foreign key Eloquent model
            // 'placeholder' => "Select a category", // placeholder for the select2 input
            'options'   => (function ($query) {
                $shading = \App\Models\Attribute::select('attr_id')
                ->where('fk_attr_category', 1)
                ->where('attr_type', 'collection')
                ->where('attr_name', 'Shading')->get()->first()->attr_id;

                return $query->orderBy('attr_val', 'desc')->where('fk_attr_id', $shading)->get();
            }),
         ]);
```

Comment: For relationships you might be able to use `relationship_name.attribute` as the name of your field. That definitely works for text inputs - not sure if it works for the Relationship field. Might want to try a simpler field like `select` at first so there's less room for error.

Comment: Ok so, I tried that and ended up with an error saying "this attribute does not exist on this collection instance" which i was expecting...

Comment: Ok so am trying a different approach by creating my own field using a custom view which i load using the view field in backpack. Now how do I get that to store data when I click on the save button on the form, cause am not really sure where and how the form is being submitted and where will I be able to handle my http request

Comment: You can read more about the Create & Update in the docs, specifically the "How it works" sections - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operation-create#how-it-works but basically you can create a method in your CrudController called `store()` or `update()` and overwrite the saving process. It's possible you don't need that at all though, if your input in the view contains the EXACT name as the column in the DB, and the content is EXCTLY as you want it stored in the DB, it'll just work. If you want to manipulate before storing, I recommend Laravel accessors and mutators, in the Model.